# How to pass UIIImage in unsigned byte format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsdata

I am making one application, in which user selects one image from photo library and then that image need to be passed on web server using soapy, format for image passing in soap in unsigned byte, i have converted UIImage into NSData, Now how do i pass that NSData as an unsigned byte format in web server.

Please help me bcoz i am really stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** indentifier of uint8 will be %s

Do this:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
if(data)
{
  Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc([data length]); // unsigned byte
  memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], [data length]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, i have done this before, but the only thing is not working is to pass that byteData in soap like this  <param_IDImage>unsignedByte</param_IDImage> so wht will be the identifier for this, previously i was using %u